# why does query in mysql works but query in php doesnt and its only due to specific columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a simple query:

```
SELECT
    job_title, 
    job_description, 
    job_tasks, 
    technology_skills, 
    job_activities
FROM 
    careeryou_db3 
WHERE 
    Job_Interests = " CIE"
```

It works perfectly in mysql giving me this result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtA2f.jpg

However, when I use this in my PHP it returns an empty data set. I did some troubleshooting by trying to query the columns one by one and it works(returning the [correct results respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi1mz.jpg).

```
SELECT 
    job_title, job_description, job_tasks 
FROM 
    careeryou_db3 
WHERE 
    Job_Interests = " CIE"
```

Apparently, when I try to query anything from the columns of [technology_skills] OR [job_activities], the php result would return as BLANK. Does anyone have any idea why? this is strange and im kinda new to this

This is my php code:

```
$query = 'SELECT job_title,job_description,job_tasks FROM    careeryou_db3 WHERE Job_Interests = " CIE" ';
$resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

$records = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
    $records[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($records);
```

Comment: The query should work exactly the same between PHP and mysql. Try turning on the mysql general_log while you run that query or echo it back out in your code, and verify that it matches what you put into mysql.

Comment: Can you provide us the PHP code you're using?

Comment: What is your php code running the query? It is returning an array of objects so you will have to loop through the array to access each result.

Comment: @aynber im sorry what is the mysql general_log again? and how do i turn that on?.. exactly! it worked for the first three columns but just returned blank when i place the [technology_skills] column into the query

Comment: @Twinfriends  $query = 'SELECT job_title,job_description,job_tasks FROM careeryou_db3 WHERE Job_Interests = " CIE" ';
            $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            
            $records = array();
            
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
                $records[] = $r;
            }
            echo json_encode($records);

Comment: @JPickup $query = 'SELECT job_title,job_description,job_tasks FROM careeryou_db3 WHERE Job_Interests = " CIE" ';
            $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            
            $records = array();
            
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
                $records[] = $r;
            }
            echo json_encode($records);

Comment: You should edit your question and poste the code there instead of posting it to a comment. By editing your question you make sure more people are going to see what you've posted.

Comment: @Twinfriends yup i just realized that and just edited it... soz im kinda new to all this haha

Comment: No problem, thats why I say it, so you know it for the future. People here on Stackoverflow really like well asked questions, good grammer, nice formating and stuff like that. You'll see, to invest 5 minutes more when you ask a question will just help you soo much to get more answers. The better you ask, the more answers you'll get.

Comment: Can you show your query with the fields you can't access, as well? The general_log requires server access to get to the log, so if you're using a shared server, it's not the best way. But more information on it can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html).

Comment: @aynber the query with the fields i cant access is the very first query i stated in the question.. thats the query i cant access. and okay im trying to find out how to get the logs

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any error on your sql syntax. Can you check the mysql logs for better error information?

See here for details
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log.html

```
[mysqld]
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

It would help how you call the mysql, place the query build code as example.

Comment: urmm sorry but i dont quite understand.. im using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth adding these lines for extra debugging to ensure your connection and query is successful.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " .  mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
....
```

Comment: Like this yes?
$resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            
            $records = array();
            
            if (!$resultset) {
                echo "Could not successfully run query ($query) from DB: " .  mysql_error();
                exit;
            }

            if (mysql_num_rows($resultset) == 0) {
                echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
                exit;
            }
            
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
                $records[] = $r;
            }

Comment: I've added it and it doesnt show any diff still blank

Comment: This is a bit of a wild card but did you mean to have a space in the where clause? -> " CIE"

Comment: What variable did you var_dump in your second screen shot of try.php?

Comment: yes there has to be a space in the " CIE"... its coz of the data in the db.. urmm what did u mean var_dump?

Comment: its so weird because the query works perfectly on phpmyadmin 
and it works on php UNTIL i add in the columns [technology_skills] or [job_activities] into the query.. then the php just returns blank.. other than that the first 3 columns in the query works as intended.. just the last two

Comment: `var_dump()` is a function you can use to print a variable but doesn't matter if you didn't use this. If you select all by using `SELECT * FROM ...` can you access the other attributes?

Comment: Could it be due to the data in the column?
This is one of the data in the [technology_skills] column...
 Analytical or scientific software — Insightful S-PLUS; SAS ; SPSS ; Wolfram Research Mathematica (see all 5 examples) Compliance software — Compliance testing software Data base user interface and query software — dBASE Plus; Microsoft Access ; SAP BusinessObjects Desktop Intelligence; Structured query language SQL (see all 5 examples) Development environment software — Microsoft Visual Basic Electronic mail software — IBM Lotus

Comment: thank you for trying to help me mate! it was greatly appreciated but it turns out it was because of my data in those columns.. "—" doesnt translate well in php haha thank you nonetheless! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the data in those columns that are conflicting with the PHP. Apparently this "—" cannot get parse into PHP which explains why the query works only in phpMyAdmin and not my PHP script.